# Show that, in general, $A^TA\neq AA^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Suppose that $A$ is a real square matrix with transpose $A^T$. I am trying to show that, in general,
$$A^TA\neq AA^T.$$
As an example, consider the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 
                                2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A^T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 
                                0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$.

Hence $AA^T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 
                                2 & 13
\end{pmatrix}$ and $A^TA=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 6 \\ 
                                6 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$, which are clearly not equal. I am wondering how this generalises to the entries of my matrix $A$. For instance, is this always true if $A$ is not symmetric?

Comment: If you want to be more general just write down generic entries for $A$, and compute both products $AA^{T}$ and $A^TA$. By setting them equal you will obtain a system of equations, the solution of which is exactly the set of matrices satisfying that condition.

Comment: Did you try your conjecture with simple non-symmetric matrices, like $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: There are some necessary or sufficient conditions, at least. For instance, orthogonal matrices commute with their transpose, since the transpose is their inverse. And there's the necessary condition that if a matrix commutes with its transpose, then every row has the same magnitude as the corresponding column.

Comment: Related: [How would the most general $2 \times 2$ normal matrix look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3258401/42969)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square matrix that satisfy $AA^T=A^TA$ is known as normal matrix.

Clearly every symmetric matrix is normal but not the converse.

For an example choose,

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0 \\ 0&1&1 \\ 1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Then $A$ is normal matrix (verify!) but clearly $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It just defines the word indicating the desired property and then shows how it is not limited to only symmetric matrices. Well, neither is the set of all matrices, so how is this a proof of the limitation of the property?

Comment: @Nij, in a way, it does because the OP asked if $AA^T\ne A^TA$ if $A$ is not symmetric. Isn't one counterexample sufficient for a claim to fail?

Comment: No, the question is to show that in general, the product with transpose is not commutative. Showing that one subset of cases makes it true does not show that it is not generally true. This could at best be a comment addressing the side issue, but really it shows the question requires clarity as to what it is asking, which would be resolved by removing the side issue, and therefore this post is not an answer either way.

Comment: Well. If this answer is not useful surely I will delete . But the question that is given in the title and OP asked at the end of the description are different . The question that asked in the description is required a counter example and question in the title required proof. But i think it's quite reasonable to consider the question in the description not in the title. If I am wrong please comment and I will remove this answer. Thanks for all your comments .